# Await loadstripe method blocking the further processing in code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a stripe checkout project but was stuck when I found that the URL is changing after clicking my plan button but was not able to provide that button value to the backend. Here is my code for front-end where I am doing this :

The problem here coming is that await loadStripe line is blocking the code from further processing and the post request is not being able to send at the backend . Here is my code :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import useState from 'react-usestateref'
import { isAuth } from "../helpers/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./Pricing.module.scss";
import ScriptTag from "react-script-tag";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

const PUBLISHABLE_KEY =
  "pk_test_463953479345937....";

export const Pricing = () => {
  const [buttonValue, setButtonValue , buttonValueRef] = useState();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setButtonValue(e.target.value);
    console.log(buttonValueRef.current);
    checkout(buttonValueRef.current);
  };
  const checkout = async (btnValue) => {
    try {
      console.log(btnValue);
      const stripe = await loadStripe(PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/checkout", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          btnValue,
        }),
      })
        .then((result) => result.json())
        .then(({ sessionID }) => stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionID }));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
return (
<div>
  <ScriptTag
    isHydrating={true}
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"
  />
<form>
        <button
          value= 'price_bdsahfbadshb'
          type="submit"
          className="btn"
          name="product"
          onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
        >
          Upgrade Now
        </button>
</div>
)
}
```

Here is my route in the backend for receiving this value :

```
router.post('/checkout' , async(req,res) => {
    const product = req.body;
    console.log(product);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `loadStripe` twice? Remove the 2nd inclusion.

Comment: I removed it then , and also I am receiving an error : Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute . I think this might be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Async and await returns promise use this code to fetch it will definitely solves

```
router.post('/checkout' , async(req,res) => {
    const product = await req.body;
    console.log(product);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any request in network tab

Comment: refresh page and again watch in network

Comment: Yeah , I refreshed it the only request I see is localhost:3000/pricing?product=price_#PRICECODE

Comment: check my route.js here : https:// pastebin.com/ivrgSn2i and controller https://pastebin.com/QHzzVAyr